# Какова совместимость ryzen и linux? Не возникают ли ошибки совместимости на аппаратном уровне?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, железо, ос

Видел в интернете отрицательный отзыв о процессоре райзен, что он имеет проблемы совместимости с ос linux. Возникают непреодолимые ошибки при работе или загрузке системы. Насколько верно это суждение? Стоит ли собирать такой компьютер для работы в линукс, в частности ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Была действительно проблема при высокой нагрузке с *некоторыми партиями* процессоров (гуглить на "segfault ryzen linux"). Но это было больше года назад; если процессор выпущен после августа 2017, то упомянутая ошибка в нем исправлена.